# Custom labels in static resource

Tags: static-resources, customlabel

I am trying to make the data-sitekey into custom label. The datasitekey is in the static resource file. I created a custom label name sitekey.
Earlier I was hardcoding the site key and it was working fine. Now it is throwing the error. **"Error for site owner: Invalid site key"**

```
<div
    class="g-recaptcha"
    data-callBack="onSuccess"
    data-expired-callback="onExpire"
    data-sitekey="sitekey">
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    window.$Label = window.$Label || {};
    $Label.sitekey = '{!JSENCODE($Label.sitekey)}';
    var sitekey = $Label.sitekey;
</script>
```

Comment: What is this for? Visualforce? Aura? LWC?

Comment: You want to put this data into a Custom Setting or even Custom Metadata, and not into a Custom Label, by the way.

Comment: This is for LWC